# JQ: Print Key and Attribute Value

Tags: jq

I've been trying to print a key and attribute value so given this JSON

```
[
  {
    "key": "foo",
    "value": { "sub" : false}
  },
  {
    "key": "bar",
    "value": { "sub" : true}
  }
]
```

I want to return something like this:

```
[
  {
    "foo": "false"
  },
  {
    "bar": "true"
  }
]
```

I'm using to_entries to do this but when I feed the JSON into JQ though I can't seem to access it correctly? I get an error:

> jq: error (at :9): Cannot index array with string "key"

[This test case](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=to_entries&j=%7B%22a%22%3A%201%2C%20%22b%22%3A%202%7D) simplifies the behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really use `to_entries` here, that creates an object out of an array of key/value objects. You're trying to map a key/value object to another object. Just map it directly.

```
map({ (.key): .value.sub })
```